# Prevent event handlers from queuing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using "One" to wire up a click handler.

Jquery's "one" method will wire up an event handler and detach it after it's first invocation, but it seems if you just click fast enough, more than one event handler may be queued up and cause the call back to run more than once.

Ex:

```
$("#button").one("click", function () {

            //run logic

});
```

How can I prevent this behavior.  I am assuming "One" will detach the handler after running it the first time, but if you click the button while it's running the call back, is it reasonable to assume it will run a second time?

Comment: which browser are you seeing this behavior in? It should be impossible. Edit: Yeah I cannot replicate this. Are you sure this is all the code you have?

Comment: I am running in IE 9 in IE comp mode. I can be wrong in my assumptions, but it seems like this would be possible in theory..

Comment: The theory is that the UI and javascript run in the same thread, so the next queued up click event happens when the javascript has fully executed its response to the first click, which includes removing the handler.

Comment: But wouldn't the second one in thory already be attached and queued when the off code runs? Meaning you will have two running in sequence (while in off mode) since they were queued up before any code to turn it off executed?

Comment: @TGH no the queue is not in javascript but the internal event queue of the browser. When the time comes to do something with the second click, there is no javascript handlers for it anymore. You should strongly consider bugs in your own code or at least provide a minimum example where you could replicate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am assuming "One" will detach the handler after running it the first time

Not true, `.one` will detach the event handler before running the handler function. If you look at [.one](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=on) source code, the `.off` is triggered before your handler function is called.

```
if (one === 1) {
    origFn = fn;
    fn = function (event) {
        jQuery().off(event);  //Your event is unregistered here
        return origFn.apply(this, arguments); //Your handler is called
    };
    fn.guid = origFn.guid || (origFn.guid = jQuery.guid++);
}
```

As Frédéric Hamidi pointed out in his comment,

> Even if the handler re-triggers the event during its execution, the actual handling of the new event will not occur until after the current handler has returned and the original event is fully resolved (possibly involving other handlers if the event is allowed to bubble up the DOM tree). By that time, the handler will have been removed in both cases.

**Proof:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/abcvW/2/

Comment: +1, that's true, but it shouldn't make a difference. Even if the handler re-triggers the event during its execution, the actual handling of the new event will not occur until after the current handler has returned and the original event is fully resolved (possibly involving other handlers if the event is allowed to bubble up the DOM tree). By that time, the handler will have been removed in both cases.